# status bar activity skips parent to return to grand-parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, statusbar

My android app uses an abstract activity, StatusActivity, for my status bar. In my status bar is a button that dispatches activity Zeta. Now say AlphaActivity dispatched BravoActivity, and then from BravoActivity someone decides to click on the button in the status bar that dispatches ZetaActivity. Now if from ZetaActivity I click the back-button, control returns to AlphaActivity as opposed to BravoActivity.

Note that I am using Alpha and Bravo as representative. Clicking the back-button in Zeta always returns to the grandparent activity.

Does anyone know how to get ZetaActivity to Always return to its parent activity as opposed to a grand-parent?